# Since when is it possible to CMD-Q Finder?

Tags: finder, shortcut, applications

I am on OSX 10.10.1.
As of very recently (can't be more than a couple of days, else I would've noticed it sooner I think), I am able to quit the Finder by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, which will *quit* the Finder app, not only close the window. There is also a Quit Finder menu entry, I don't know if that was there before. I asked someone who also uses Yosemite and as expected, they can't do it.

The question is: Why is this suddenly possible, has anyone else experienced it and how can I revert this change?

Comment: Onyx, Cocktail, Secrets etc could all enable that. It's a toggle-able item. If you're any good with terminal it's com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem bool [but I'm no good with terminal so idk how to convert that info to a terminal command]

Comment: You're right, that was it! I use Onyx, but can't remember having checked the box.

Comment: Cool. I'll drop it to an answer for future users - though I hope some kind soul will edit in the correct way to do it in Terminal, for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quit menu item in Finder can be enabled by

- Onyx, Cocktail, Secrets etc
- Directly in Terminal with `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES`

Comment: Thank you for the edit patrix, makes it a good Question & Answer now.